# ErrorException in Authen.php line 19: Undefined variable: guard

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

*Authen.php file look like* :-

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class Authen
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (!Auth::guard($guard)->check()) 
        {
          return redirect()->route('/');   
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

I don't know whats wrong with this file , route file is correct but whenever i want to go dashboard this error happen **ErrorException in Authen.php line 19:
Undefined variable: guard**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
 all your routes
}
```

hope it will solve your error

Comment: Route::group(['middleware'=>['authen','roles']],function(){
 Route::get('/dashboard',['as'=>'dashboard', 'uses'=> 'dashboardController@dashboard']);
});

Comment: you need the web middleware bro